# Changing the color of the selected spinner item

Tags: android, android-spinner

How do I change the text color of the selected item of a spinner?
For reference: the color of "United Kingdom", which was the item shown before the spinner opened.

[image]

Here is my **spinner_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:padding="5dip"
/>
```

My **spinner_dropdown_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="5dip"
/>
```

And my implementation:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.kindle_stores, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
```